# Hiding a stack snippet does not halt execution

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

example:

[Using setInterval with requestAnimationFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879439/using-setinterval-with-requestanimationframe/25879656#25879656)

If you start the first snippet, then press "Hide Results", the code continues to run in the background. This means that if it's something that runs for a long time and doesn't have a way to stop the running, it will keep on running in the background, putting a (sometimes quite severe) drain on the client. I have a quite decent computer, yet I notice the slowdown when running the snippet.

This seems like something that could be used maliciously.

Comment: It would definitely be preferable if they are able to remove instead of hide the snippet, but still be able to re-add it if you want to run the snippet again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've modified the code so that hiding a snippet deletes the iframe. Running after that point creates a new iframe and so forth. This should help quite a bit.